# Data inside MySQL tables comparison tools

Tags: mysql, comparison

I need a tool for Windows that:

- allows me to compare the data inside two tables which have the same column name
- shows me the disaligned data
- allows me to choose a set of rows / cells to copy to the other table

Something very similar to Beyond Compare / Araxis Merge but for comparing tables / views

The concept is pretty easy:

- file comparer base their comparison on the file name. Here a join criteria would been provided
- file comparer allows to "copy to left" to overwrite the text inside a file; this software should do the same with the "cell" of a database (cell = one column of one row returned by a query)

Does something similar exist already?

Answer (score 3):

Many years ago I used [SQL Delta](http://www.sqldelta.com/index?page=deltamysql) for this purpose.  I assume it's still good.  A single license is $185 though.

Comment: The license is pretty expensive :( the tool worths that price?

Comment: They have a free [14 day trail](http://www.sqldelta.com/index?page=download).  As to whether it's worth it, I haven't compared it to other tools that are out there.

Answer (score 2):

*Here are some suggestions for you*

- You should take a look at [Devart's](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/) database compare tools for MySQL from it's official website

> DbForge Data Compare for MySQL serves for comparing and synchronizing
>   data in MySQL, Percona, MariaDB databases. The tool gives clear view
>   of differences between data, allows analyzing them, generates
>   synchronization script, and applies changes at a glance. It also
>   allows scheduling regular MySQL data comparisons using command line.

- Compare data in MySQL databases to see changes
- Analyze data differences between two databases
- Synchronize two databases that went out of sync
- Generate data comparison reports in Excel and HTML formats
- Copy look-up data from development database to production
- Schedule comparison tasks through command line interface

**30 Days Free Trial**

---

- [Toad™](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-mysql/) for MySQL is a freeware development tool that enables you to quickly and efficiently create and execute queries, automate database object management, and develop SQL code. Toad MySQL provides utilities to compare, extract, and search for objects. The MySQL tool also enables you to record and play back keyboard commands, and transfer data across MySQL databases. The MySQL developer tool increases efficiency by helping you manage projects, import/export data, and administer the database.
- Version control integration — Enables you to check in and check out
  code from within the editor to reduce the risk of errors.
- Macro record and playback — Allows you to record and play back
  keyboard commands.
- Database browser — Reorganizes and manages objects and object types.
- Code snippet editor — Speeds navigation by enabling you to create and
  alter code snippets for expand-and-collapse code blocks.
- Security manager — Provides you with better system control by
  permitting or restricting user access to specific Toad features.
- SQL editor — Allows you to create, execute, modify, and save queries;
  view and edit data; and process DDL commands from an intuitive
  interface.
- Fast, multi-tabbed schema browser — Displays and manages database
  objects graphically.
- DB extract, compare-and-search utility — Allows you to compare two
  MySQL databases, view the differences, and create the script to
  update the target.
- Import/Export utility — Enables you to transfer data across MySQL
  databases

---

- Top rated is [MySQL Comparison Bundle From Red-gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-bundle/) but its expensive,still worh checking this out,It offers a 14-day free trial

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a distributed version control system for databases, check out [Klonio](https://klonio.com). Its like Git/GitHub for databases. The user interface/commands have been modelled similar to Git, so you can run a `klonio diff` to get what you want.

Comment: Klonio currently only exists as Beta, but thanks anyway as s it looks extremely promising. I signed up for "pin me when stable"